# RuntimeEnvironment.application in Robolectric tests after AndroidStudio 2.3 update

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, robolectric

We are using Robolectric for tests in Android Studio.

After a recent update from 2.2.x to 2.3 all my tests run with Robolectric (i.e. `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)`) fail.

More specifically, I'm getting a ClassCastException here, as it seems that `RuntimeEnvironment.application` is no longer returning the custom application type created for test purposes.

```
MyTestApplication testApp = (MyTestApplication) RuntimeEnvironment.application;
// do something with testApp
```

Apparently I'm getting a plain old `android.app.Application` instead of the expected type...

The crux:

- **Neither tests, nor config were changed**, the only thing I did was the AndroidStudio update (I did `git reset --hard` just to make sure...).
- **On the command line my tests run just fine,** which makes me think this might be an issue with the test runner in Android Studio.

:(

I think I tried just about everything in Android Studio, like clean/rebuild, resync gradle files, invalid cache + restart... I tried to re-download and reinstall Android Studio (2.2.3 and 2.3 versions). I cleaned my local gradle cache and my local `.m2` repo just to make sure, but to no avail... :(

Comment: Same issue... haven't figured anything out so far.

Comment: AS is quite tedious about dependencies change and sometimes require to invalidate caches and restart?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

1. Go to *Run > Edit Configuration*
2. then in the Run/Debug Configurations for *JUnit > java in app*
3. Add `$MODULE_DIR$` in the field *Working directory*.